# UnboundLocalError: local variable

Tags: python, urllib2

My code is the following:

```
search_request = urllib2.Request(url,data=tmp_file_name,headers={'X-Requested-With':'WoMenShi888XMLHttpRequestWin'})
#print search_request.get_method()
try:
    search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    pass
html_data = search_response.read()
print html_data
```

but when I run it I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\MyProjects\python\lfi_tmp.py", line 78, in <module>
    print hello_lfi()
  File "G:\MyProjects\python\lfi_tmp.py", line 70, in hello_lfi
    html_data = search_response.read()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'search_response' referenced before assignment
```

I tried adding

```
global search_response
```

and run again, I get an exception like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\MyProjects\python\lfi_tmp.py", line 78, in <modul
    print hello_lfi()
  File "G:\MyProjects\python\lfi_tmp.py", line 70, in hello_
    html_data = search_response.read()
NameError: global name 'search_response' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting `HTTPError` you have no `search_response` variable. So this line:

```
html_data = search_response.read()
```

raises your error, because you are attempting to access `search_response` that wasn't declared. I think that you should replace the `html_data = search_response.read()` line like this for example:

```
search_request = urllib2.Request(url,data=tmp_file_name,headers={'X-Requested-With':'WoMenShi888XMLHttpRequestWin'})
    #print search_request.get_method()
try:
    search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
    html_data = search_response.read()  #New here
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    html_data = "error" #And here

print html_data
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is going to the `exception` in the code below, where `search_response` variable is not set.

```
try:
    search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    pass
html_data = search_response.read()
print html_data
```

instead of using `pass`, raise an Error or set `search_response` variable to `None`.

maybe something like:

```
try:
    search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    raise SomeError
html_data = search_response.read()
print html_data
```

or

```
try:
    search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    search_response = None
if html_data:
    html_data = search_response.read()
    print html_data
else:
    # Do something else
```